# METAFONT MiKTeX doesn't relax

Tags: miktex, metafont

This is what happens when I say `\relax` to MiKTeX's METAFONT, under Windows.
[image: Emergency stop]

On the TeXLive's version of METAFONT on Linux it behaves fine.  Why is that?

MiKTeX's MetaPost on Windows instead works just fine.
[image]

Comment: This is not a bug tracker. Go to https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is at last an bug report and off topic here.